# How do I fix this main menu that shows generic application names?

Tags: xubuntu, menu, settings

I was playing around somewhere tweaking my Xubuntu main menu. All I can see now is the generic names for the installed applications, for example, `Google Chrome` and `Firefox` both are displayed as `Web Browser`. How can restore it?

[image]

Comment: what did you do?if you can tell, that might help.  Well i don't know specifically about the xubuntu but you can try changing the name of the icon file in /usr/share/applications

Comment: Oh God! renaming all the items? transmission, gedit even terminal?? I was playing around the settings, where I checked some box saying `use general names` or something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After playing around a little more, I figured out myself the solution.

Right clicking on the main menu > `properties` opens the Applications Menu, where there exist a checkbox that says `Show generic application names`, uncheck it.
[image: Application Menu]

Now everything looks great! 
[image: reset to default]